# How can you localize Telerik Ui for Blazor?

Tags: telerik, blazor, blazor-server-side

How can the [Telerik Ui for Blazor](https://www.telerik.com/blazor-ui) be localized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following https://docs.telerik.com/blazor-ui/globalization/localization, I have created the *.resx files for a German translation of the components and put them there: https://github.com/SeppPenner/Telerik.Ui.for.Blazor.German.Resources.

Use it as you like :)

Comment: There is now a public repo where everyone can contribute (and also take) translations https://github.com/telerik/blazor-ui-messages
I have added the latest version from the repo you provided to it, and I have linked back to this thread and your repo. Thank you for your contribution

Comment: @rdmptn Thank you for that, I will keep it in mind and cross-link your repository as well :)